# Python printing None in console for no obvious reason?

Tags: python, variables, printing, integer, nonetype

My program draws boxes in a grid. Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/cMEJAAES

The idea here is I need a debug method. It should print the coordinates of the box the turtle just drew, and it's color. For some reason, the it prints fine but with a random None in the middle. Here's an example of some console output:

```
Reading map data....
Drew tile 1 (1,1)
None as color 3
Drew tile 2 (1,2)
None as color 0
```

Here's my code:

```
#Define our map to draw.
map = [3,           #Set row width.
        3, 0, 0,    #Row data.
        0, 2, 1,
        2, 1, 1]
```

*[...]*

```
def drawmap(m):
#Print the entire map.
    for x in range (0, len(m)):
        if x == 0:
            print("Reading map data....") #Not really, just skipping index 0.
        else:
            draw_tile(map[x])
            lastbox = x
            tileinfo(x)
            move(m, lastbox)

def tileinfo(index):
    print ("Drew tile ", end='')
    print (index, end='')
    print (getcoords(index), end='')
    print (" as color ", end='')
    print (map[index])

def getcoords(index):
    print (" (", end='')
    print ((index // map[0]) + 1, end='')
    print (",", end='')
    if (index % map[0]) == 0:
        print (map[0], end='')
    else:
        print (index % map[0], end='')
    print (")")
```

Why would this be happening?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

`getcoords` returns `None`, so:

```
print (getcoords(index), end='')
```

prints a `None` to the console.

Comment: Oh duh! Thank you so much. Can't print a function that just prints things. Sorry for such a dumb question! I'll be downvoted to oblivion anyway :S